# mPDF library: force download file

Tags: php, mpdf

Hi I treid to generate a simple pdf file using mPDF library but, when I force the download of the file I obtain an Error code 500.

this is my code:

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',20,20,47,47,10,10); 
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output("my_filename.pdf","D");
```

Comment: is this your full code?

Comment: in case of error 500 go to your Apache (if you are using Apache) log (in linux its `/var/log/apache2`) and check what real error message is

Comment: To make the correct hint @pavlovich gave more precise: php logs errors into an error log file (unless that is explicitly switched off). Typically that is the error log file the http server maintains, since php is typically used as module inside the http server. In that log file you will find a specific hint as to where your script fails. That helps a lot to understand what is going on.

Comment: No it isn't my full code, it is only the final part. If I use 
$mypdf->Output();
It works but it doesn't save. Unfortunately I'm on a shared host and I can't see the log file